# Не отображается иконка приложения - C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил иконку в свойствах проекта, после компиляции у приложения отображается стандартная иконка. Эта же иконка прекрасно работает в WPF приложении.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А каким образом вы добавляли иконку?

Comment: Проект -> Свойства -> Значёк и манифест -> Обзор -> Ок

Comment: А какого формата ваша иконка?

Comment: Иконка формата ico

Comment: Если запускать не из студии, иконка тоже не отображается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дизайнер view -> кликни на форму -> Properties -> Icon -> клик на [...] -> выбери иконку формата .ico -> OK

**UPDATE:**

Если поставить таким образом, то и значок формы и тот значок который отображается в панели задач - будет одинаковым. А если поставить через Свойства проекта -> Значок и манифест, то после компиляции поменяется иконка .exe файла. ("Путь проекта"/bin/Debug (или Release))

Comment: Изменит только иконку формы, а не приложения

Comment: Смотрите, если поставить таким образом, то и значок формы и тот значок который отображается в панели задач - будет одинаковым. А через свойства проекта (Значок и манифест) - после компиляции поменяется иконка .exe файла.

Comment: @SeM добавьте это в ваш ответ и опишите по подробнее